# Открыть определенную папку

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте! Смог я открыть корневую директорию и просмотреть там список файлов, а вот просмотреть отдельную папку не получается, знаю что нужно заюзать функцию

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory('DCIM', {create: true}, function(dirEntry)
```

но не знаю куда её засунуть, подскажите пожалуйста, код ниже тот который нужно отредактировать:
Пишу под Android, iOS, BlackBerry

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // получаем обьект филисистем
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        }
        
        function toArray(list) {
          return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
        }
    
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            //   смотрим в лог как там? имя появилось?
             console.log(fileSystem.name);
            
            var dirReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
            //var getDir = fileSystem.root.getDirectory('DCIM', {create: true}, function(dirEntry) {
              var entries = [];
              var readEntries = function() {
                 dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
                     if (results.length) {
                        entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
                        listResults(entries); 
                    }
                }, fail);
              };
              readEntries(); // Start reading dirs. 
        }
 
        function fail(evt) {
            //   читаем проблеммы
            console.log("@ @ @ @ @ @ Error trololo " + evt.target.error.code);
        }
    
        function listResults(entries) {
              entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                    if (entry.isDirectory) { 
                        console.log('! ! ! ! ! ! is Directory '); 
                    } else {
                        console.log('! ! ! ! ! ! is FILE ');
                    }
                        //console.log("@ @ @ @ @ @ Names and others: " + entry.name);
                        alert(entry.name);
              });
     }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, это нереально =8)

Comment: Может засчитаешь мой коммент как правильный ответ?))))

Comment: @Gorets, почему? Речь вроде бы о [FileSystem API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/).

Comment: Согласно [спецификации](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/#widl-DirectoryEntry-getDirectory-void-DOMString-path-Flags-options-EntryCallback-successCallback-ErrorCallback-errorCallback) вам нужно вместо получения reader-a корня `fileSystem.root.createReader();` сначала получить нужную директорию:
    
    filesystem.root.getDirectory(...)

а уже в callback-функции получать reader для найденной директории.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ перенесен из [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/119173/15) вопроса автором.

Ответ на вопрос:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Local File System Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            // получаем обьект филисистем
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
        }
        
        function toArray(list) {
          return Array.prototype.slice.call(list || [], 0);
        }
    
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        
             //console.log(fileSystem.name);
             
                var dirReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
                  var entries = [];
                  var readEntries = function() {
                     dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
                         if (results.length) {
                            entries = entries.concat(toArray(results));
                            listResults(entries); 
                        }
                    }, fail);
                  };
                  readEntries();
        }
        
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getDirectory("DCIM", {create: false, exclusive: false}, getDirSuccess, fail);
        }
        
        function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
            // Get a directory reader
            var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
         
            // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
            directoryReader.readEntries(listResults, fail);
        }

        function fail(evt) {
            //   читаем проблеммы
            console.log("Error trololo " + evt.target.error.code);
        }
    
        function listResults(entries) {
              entries.forEach(function(entry) {
                    alert(entry.name);
              });
     }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Local File System</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Этот код читает список файлов в папке DCIM телефона и выводит алертом список файлов и папок в нем.